# Getting error while creating a desktop shortcut in UWP code

Tags: uwp, desktop, shortcut

I am getting this error while creating a desktop shortcut in my UWP code - The "windows.desktopAppMigration" Extension can't be declared outside of Full Trust EntryPoint(either inherited from Application or declared in the Extension)

```
<Package xmlns:rescap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities/3"
IgnorableNamespaces="rescap3">
<Applications>
<Application>
  <Extensions>
    <rescap3:Extension Category="windows.desktopAppMigration">
      <rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
        <rescap3:DesktopApp AumId="[your_app_aumid]" />
        <rescap3:DesktopApp ShortcutPath="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\[my_app].lnk" />
        <rescap3:DesktopApp ShortcutPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\[my_app].lnk" />
        <rescap3:DesktopApp ShortcutPath="%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\[my_app_folder]\[my_app].lnk"/>
     </rescap3:DesktopAppMigration>
    </rescap3:Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it means you need `EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication"` in the `<Application>` element, as in [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/blob/c6f229d000f2fecf56724ebf55adb1ccb6913f24/Samples/DesktopAppTransition/PhotoStoreDemo.Package/package.appxmanifest#L25).